# Basis of the special form

Tags: combinatorics, finite-fields, primitive-roots

Let $R = \mathrm{GF}(q)$, $S = \mathrm{GF}(q^n), \ n\geq 2$ be extension of $R$, $h$ be a primitive element of $S$. I want to count or estimate the number $N$ of basis of the following form.
Let $$\vec{\beta} = (\beta_0,\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_{n-1})$$ be a basis of the space $_RS$ with the property that there exists $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that
$$
\vec{\beta'} = (\beta_0,\ldots,\beta_{k-1},h\beta_k,\ldots,h\beta_{n-1}) 
$$
is a basis of the space $_RS$.

It is easily to see that  $N\geq (q^n-q)\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}(q^n-2q^{j}+q^{j-1})$. This estimation obtained from the case $k = n-1$

It is also easily to see, that the basis of the form $(e,h,\ldots, h^{n-1})$ has the desirable property.
My another question is: is there another approaches for construction such basis?

Comment: Crossposted http://mathoverflow.net/questions/236402/basises-of-the-special-form

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers, Yes $\vec{\beta}$ is a collection of n elements of the vector space $_RS$.  And $(e,h,\ldots,h^{n-1})\in S^n$ it is not a single vector. Have I answered in your question?